# Idiomatic way to dispatch an action on a subcomponent in react redux without passing in props all the way through

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am currently learning how to use react, redux, and react-redux and have a rather simple need. I want to render something akin to the following...

```
--------------------------------
| title 1         |----------| | 
| description 1   | button 1 | |
| desc... cont.   |----------| |
|------------------------------|
| title 2         |----------| | 
| description 2   | button 2 | |
| desc2... cont.  |----------| |
|------------------------------|
| title 3         |----------| | 
| description 3   | button 3 | |
| desc3... cont.  |----------| |
|------------------------------|
```

This represents a list of `Items`. Each `Item` (3 shown in the diagram) has a `title` and a `description`. When I click the button I want perform some action for that `Item`, such as displaying an alert box with the `Item's` title.

I managed to a working sample based on the [Redux Tutorial](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html). I ended up with 1 container (smart) component named `ItemsContainer.tsx` and two Presentation (dumb) components named `ItemList.tsx` (the list) and `Item.tsx` (an individual item). Hierarchically it looks like this...

```
App
-- ItemsContainer
---- ItemList
------ Item
------ Item
```

However, like the Redux Tutorial this required that I passed the `onClick` function through each of the presentation components via props. If I had a much deeper nesting this could become burdensome so I am attempting to find another way.

What I have now are two container components `ItemListContainer.tsx`, `ItemContainer.tsx` and two presentation components `ItemList.tsx` and `Item.tsx`. However, whenever I click on the button my alert box simply states `[Object object]`. I believe what is happening is that am actually receiving the button click's event, rather than the `Item.id` but I am not sure where to go from here to make sure the proper function is assigned to the onClick. Hierarchically it looks like this...

```
App
-- ItemListContainer
---- ItemList
------ ItemContainer
-------- Item
-------- Item
```

The code is as follows...

```typescript
// app.tsx
import * as React from 'react';
import { ItemListContainer } from '../addItem/ItemListContainer';

export const App = () => {
    return <div><ItemListContainer/></div>;
};
```

```typescript
// itemListContainer.tsx
import { ItemList } from './itemList';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


function mapStateToProps(state: any): any {
    return {
        items: state.items
    }
}

export const ItemListContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, null)(ItemList);
```

```typescript
// itemList.tsx
import * as React from 'react';
import { IItems, IItemSummary } from '../../data/Items/models/Item';
import { ItemContainer } from './ItemContainer';

export const ItemList = (props: IItems) => {

    let divStyle = {
            position: 'block',
            border: 'solid #aeb0b5 1px',
            overflowY: 'auto',
            overflowX: 'hidden',
            width: 650,
            height: 300
    };

    return (
        <div style={divStyle}>
            {
                props.items.map(function (item: IItemSummary) {
                    return <ItemContainer {...item} />;
                })
            }
        </div>
    );
};
```

```typescript
// itemContainer.tsx
import { Item } from './Item';
import { IItems } from '../../data/Items/models/Item';
import { removeItem } from "../../data/Items/actions/initDashboardItems"
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


function mapStateToProps(state: any): any {
    return {
        items: state.items
    };
}


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any): any => {
    return {
        onClick: (id: any) => {
            alert(id);
        }
    };
};

export const ItemContainer = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Item);
```

```typescript
// item.tsx
import * as React from 'react';
import { IItemSummary } from '../../data/items/models/item';

export const item = (props: IItemSummary) => {

    let outerDiv = {
            position: 'relative',
            borderBottom: 'solid #aeb0b5 1px',
            width: '650px'
        };

        let textDiv = {
            position: 'relative',
            width: '500px',
            padding: 5
        };

        let buttonDiv = {
            position: 'absolute',
            top: '5px',
            right: '10px',
            padding: 5
        };

    return (
        <div style={outerDiv}>
            <div style={textDiv}><strong>{props.title}</strong></div>
            <div style={textDiv}>{props.description}</div>
            <div style={buttonDiv}><button onClick={props.onClick}>Add Chart</button></div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

While I ultimately need to resolve how to wire the proper function to the onclick with React and Redux I also want to know what is the idiomatic React Redux way to structure this code for the UI described at the top of this post?

Answer (score 0):

> If I had a much deeper nesting this could become burdensome so I am attempting to find another way

You would pass in the the props as much as you can (using dumb components) but at any point you are free to create a new smart component that can be put anywhere (inside a dumb component or inside another smart component).

Answer (score 0):

The solution for fixing the issue with improper wiring of the `onClick` was to modify the item.tsx file like so...

```
// item.tsx
import * as React from 'react';
import { IItemSummary } from '../../data/items/models/item';

export const item = (props: IItemSummary) => {

    const clickHandler = () => props.onClick(props.title);

    // style stuff omitted for clarity

    return (
        <div style={outerDiv}>
            <div style={textDiv}><strong>{props.title}</strong></div>
            <div style={textDiv}>{props.description}</div>
            <div style={buttonDiv}><button onClick={clickHandler}>Add Chart</button></div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

An explicit `clickHandler` function was introduced so that the props.title could be passed into the props.onClick method.

I am still not sure if this is idiomatic react-redux and may update this answer should a more appropriate method be found.

*(Thanks to acemarke and others on the Redux community channel on discordapp.com for their assistance)*